# Getting debian to use graphics card instead of integrated cpu

Tags: debian, nvidia

I have an Asus FX706LI running Debian unstable. It seems only to run from the integrated graphics on the CPU, and not the graphics card. How might I get it to run only from the graphics card? It uses a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 and an i5-10300H.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the latest NVIDIA driver installed, you can use the following command to force most programs to run on the dedicated NVIDIA card.

```bash
env __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 \
    __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia \
    __VK_LAYER_NV_optimus=NVIDIA_only \
    VK_DRIVER_FILES=/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json \
    <command>
```

You can create a script, for example `nv-run', that runs the command with these environment variables set.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
env __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia __VK_LAYER_NV_optimus=NVIDIA_only VK_DRIVER_FILES=/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=nvidia "$@"
```

Then use `nv-run <command>` to run a program on the NVIDIA card.

---

Most laptops also support disabling onboard graphics via firmware settings. This allows you to run Debian with dedicated graphics exlusively.